# Block inside block = EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a singleton class the handle all the Game Center logic:

```
typedef void (^GameCenterCallbackFinishUpdating)();

- (void)getAllMatches:(GameCenterCallbackFinishUpdating)onComplete
{
    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)
    {      
        //Do stuff here... 
        onComplete();
    }];
}
```

From another viewController I use:

```
[[GameCenterHelper sharedHelper] getAllMatches:^{

    [self.myTableView reloadData]; 

}];
```

It works great when I'm in the app, but once I close the app (background) and then start it up again, I get:

```
    onComplete();     ---- Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xc)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `if (onComplete) onComplete();`

Comment: Thats works. Thanks! It would still be interesting to know why the app crashes?

Comment: because the blocks are objects and if any block is `nil` and you try to call them, it crashes the application. somewhere and somehow this block becomes `nil` before you call it. the `if (...)` statement helps you to prevent to call a `nil` pointer, so the application won't crash.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot :) If you submit your reply as an answer I will accept it

Comment: shall I make an answer of it you to accept it?

Comment: Sure, if you want the credit :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***some background info:** the blocks are objects and if any block is* `nil` *and you try to call them, it crashes the application.*

somewhere and somehow the block `onComplete` becomes `nil` before you call it. the following `if (...)` statement helps you to prevent to call a `nil` pointer, so the application won't crash.

```
if (onComplete) onComplete();
```

Comment: The `blocks are objects` statement seems rather irrelevant, could you provide more context on how that information is relevant to the rest of the answer?

Comment: yes, it seems very relevant, because every object can be `nil` pointer, and the blocks are objects rather than functions or methods. what would you like to know about the block exactly?

Comment: The terminology is a bit wrong there. An object can not be `nil`, but you can have a pointer to `nil`, as a result the more important fact here is that the variable `onComplete` is pointing to nothing. At this point it behaves like calling a function pointer that has been assigned `NULL` e.g. Crash

Comment: @Paul.s, yep, I agree with you, this terminology is not quite correct, because, as you said, the pointer can be `nil`. what I liked to tell here is many developers believe the block are like the function or methods and they never think the pointer to the block can be `nil` and somehow they have to manage this situation in the application. I just liked to show this important difference here, there are many more professional documentations of the blocks on the Apple official site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @holex and @Paul.s for explaining it well.
I had the similar situation where I was sending block as method parameter(`completionHandler`).

```
- (void)callX:(NSString *)xyz withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *response))completion
{
    completion(something);
}
```

And there are two situations either I am using this block like:

```
[MyClass sharedInstance] callX:@"abc" withCompletionHandler:^(NSString *response) {
    if (response) {
        //do something
    }
}];
```

or this block could be `nil` as method parameter:

```
[MyClass sharedInstance] callX:@"abc" withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

In second case when block was being passed `nil` as method parameter this caused `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on **completion()**. So as @holex states that *the blocks are objects and if any block is nil and you try to call them, it crashes the application.*
A single if saves lot of my time

```
- (void)callX:(NSString *)xyz withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *response))completion
{
    if (completion)
        completion(something);
}
```

P.S: this explanation only for **`NERDS`** like me. | ' L ' |